# How to simulate mouse wheel on a canvas?

Tags: javascript

I have a physical simulation going on over a canvas element, and you can zoom in and zoom out within this canvas element by using your mouse wheel. I would like to trigger the mouse wheel programmatically.
Is there a possibility to simulate a user using the mouse wheel on a canvas element?
I had no luck creating a new WheelEvent and dispatching it on the canvas.

```
var wheelEvent = new WheelEvent(   'wheel', { deltaY: 120 } );
document.getElementById('canvas').dispatchEvent(wheelEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example from the GitHub repo [Canvas Zoom Example](https://gist.github.com/KennyRedman/50d636b7eb43a01bb61c)

Comment: This does scale the canvas, but does not simulate some wheel event.